# Is there a way to start just an app on secondary screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-environments, 16.10, xrandr, i3-wm

I am using i3wm with xrandr to manage multi-monitors,
 but what I want is ,instead of having entire DE on secondary, just to start an app there without DE for instance google-chrome .

The reason I want this is when using multi-displays , even though I initiate the second with the `--noprimary` option ,icons on the tray of my status bar goes to the secondary screen.And also nitrogen just shows the image on secondary regardless of its settings.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

So the issues is with the bar moving to the secondary screen? Try this maybe:
https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_tray_output

Or if you want specific applications on specific screens you can try this: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#workspace_screen

Comment: thanks that definitely fixes the issue though primary won't work i should explicitly define the monitor name .
But nitrogen issue still continues nitrogen does not seem to understand about primary and always shows background just in secondary